# How to check if 2 rows have same data in a table in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have the following query..now i have to check if the same columns have same data..

Can anyone help me with the query pls

```
SELECT 
   FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Company, TaxExempt, 
   AddressTitle, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, [State], ZipCode, Country,
   PhoneNumber, EmailID, 
   o.OrderNumber, o.PONumber
FROM 
   CustomerAddresses ca 
    JOIN Orders o 
         ON ca.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE 
   AddressTitle='Billing'
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can you post some sample data and what exactly you are looking to compare?

Comment: you want query for 2 rows have same data or 2 columns have same data?

Comment: Do you want to find out duplicate rows or duplicate data in selected columns only?

Comment: I have to check if 2 rows have same data..

Comment: and what are the columns are do you want to check?

Comment: for example city name is same in 2 rows ,say city = 'Staten Island' then what is the query to check if city name is same in two rows

Comment: all the columns mentioned in my question..

Comment: Select city, count(city) from CustomerAddresses Group By city Having count(city) > 1

Comment: place all columns in select and group by clause. i think you can use Marc Gravell's solution.

Answer (score 6):

A common trick is to *group by everything* and count:

```
SELECT count(1) as [Count],
   FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Company, TaxExempt, 
   AddressTitle, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, [State], ZipCode, Country,
   PhoneNumber, EmailID, 
   o.OrderNumber, o.PONumber
FROM 
   CustomerAddresses ca 
    JOIN Orders o 
         ON ca.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE 
   AddressTitle='Billing'
group by 
   FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Company, TaxExempt, 
   AddressTitle, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, [State], ZipCode, Country,
   PhoneNumber, EmailID, 
   o.OrderNumber, o.PONumber
```

You can add:

```
having count(1) > 1
```

at the bottom if you only care about duplicates and don't want to see singles.

Comment: is it require to place all columns in select statement?

Comment: Anything that is in a group by must also be in the select statement.

Comment: @nik0lias that is not true; you can't have something in the `select` that is not in the `group by` (except for aggregating operations), but you are **not** required to include the `group by` columns in the `select`

Comment: @Nimesh no, you don't need to - you can just remove everything after the `count(1) as [Count]` in the `select` if you like. Of course, then you don't know **what** is duplicated... and you might want to further aggregate the duplicates into a `count`, because getting a column with `2`,`2`,`3`,`2` by itself isn't very useful

Comment: @Nimesh that depends on what exactly you are measuring... and if there are only a few duplicates, bandwidth concerns are pretty much moot

Comment: @Nimesh note that the above looks for exact duplicates in **all** columns; to check for individual columns combined is much trickier.

Comment: Is it possible to assign only `group by [all columns]` with just `count(1)` in `select` to get same result.

Comment: @Nimesh I don't understand the question

Comment: is it possible to get same result with this query.

`SELECT count(1) as [Count]
FROM 
   CustomerAddresses ca 
    JOIN Orders o 
         ON ca.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE 
   AddressTitle='Billing'
group by 
   FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Company, TaxExempt, 
   AddressTitle, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, [State], ZipCode, Country,
   PhoneNumber, EmailID, 
   o.OrderNumber, o.PONumber`

Comment: @Nimesh define "same result". Frankly, you could answer this yourself by trying a few things in SSMS

Comment: @MarcGravell - so you are right, I was always taught to include both so assumed it was required, seems it isn't!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to find all the rows where grouping them produce count larger than one.  Then join that result back to the CustomerAddress table to get the ID of each address.

```
WITH Billing_CTE
  (SELECT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Company, TaxExempt, AddressTitle, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, [State], ZipCode, Country, PhoneNumber, EmailID, o.OrderNumber, o.PONumber, Count(1) AS [DupCount]
   FROM CustomerAddresses ca
   JOIN Orders o ON ca.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
   WHERE AddressTitle='Billing'
   GROUP BY FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Company, TaxExempt, AddressTitle, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, [State], ZipCode, Country, PhoneNumber, EmailID, o.OrderNumber, o.PONumber HAVING Count(1) > 1)
SELECT ca.CustomerId,
       o.OrderNumber,
       o.PONumber
FROM Billing_CTE b
JOIN Oderers o ON b.OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber
AND b.PONumber = o.PONumber
```